# System.Web.Extensions does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'WebForms.js'

Tags: asp.net, .net

I've a web project not created by me. Originally it was running in a newer version .net however the server I need it to run on only has .net 4 so I changed the .net version and rebuilt the project.
It runs fine on my development laptop but when on the server I get this error:

> The assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not contain a Web resource that
> has the name 'WebForms.js'. Make sure that the resource name is
> spelled correctly. Make sure that the application references the
> correct version of an ASP.NET AJAX Framework assembly.

I've been searching but as of yet I've not found the solution.